# SDL_RenderCopy() unexpected behaviour

Tags: c++, pointers, sdl, sdl-2

I'm pretty sure this is not unexpected at all, I'm probably misunderstanding something. I'm trying to call one of the overloaded constructors as such:

`SDL_RenderCopy(SDL_Renderer*, SDL_Texture*, SDL_Rect*, SDL_Rect*);`

The problem came when I made a static method in a class to retrieve SDL_Rect pointers as such:

```
static SDL_Rect* getRectangle(rect r) {
    SDL_Rect rectangle{ r.x, r.y, r.w, r.h };
    return &rectangle;
}
```

So the call is like:

```
SDL_Rect* r = MyClass::getRectangle(srcRect);
SDL_Rect* r2 = MyClass::getRectangle(destRect);
```

```
SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, r, r2);
```

They are all pointers and are returning coherent values, but for some reason I don't understand, the rectangles that I'm fetching from my class when passed to SDL, are not scaling according to the values of the rectangles. But if I change my static method to return a copy of `SDL_Rect`, everything works as expected, as such:

```
static SDL_Rect getRectangle(rect r) {
    SDL_Rect rectangle{ r.x, r.y, r.w, r.h };
    return rectangle;
}
```

And the call:

```
SDL_Rect r = Video::getRectangle(srcRect);
SDL_Rect r2 = Video::getRectangle(destRect);
```

`SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, &r, &r2);`

Comment: Is it because SDL_Rect is a struct and not on the heap and therefore gets destroyed at the end of the scope and therefore I can't use pointers to it outside of the scope? (I mean, I can, but the memory no longer has my data)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your function `getRectangle()`:

```
static SDL_Rect* getRectangle(rect r) {
    SDL_Rect rectangle{ r.x, r.y, r.w, r.h };
    return &rectangle;
}
```

You are returning the address of an object, `rectangle`, that has automatic storage duration. Therefore, the object doesn't exist after the control returns from the function.

---

You may want to allocate an `SDL_Rect` on the heap and return its address instead:

```
static SDL_Rect* getRectangle(rect r) {
    return new SDL_Rect{ r.x, r.y, r.w, r.h };
}
```

Comment: Yeah thats what I thought. And I had no idea I could allocate a struct like this! I thought I had to make a class to be able to use `new` and get a pointer as return. Thank you very very much!

Comment: In `c++` a class or struct are the actually the same with the difference being that a struct all members are public by default and a class they are private.

Comment: Right, you can even use `new` with fundamental types. For example: `int* p = new int(1)`.

Comment: Out of curiosity: Why not `static SDL_Rect getRectangle(rect r) { return SDL_Rect{ r.x, r.y, r.w, r.h }; }`? What has been `new`ed should be `delete`d. That's not an issue in my case.

Comment: Well, I apologize, I mostly come from C# and I always differentiate them by thinking that structs were passed as value instead of reference and therefore I could never allocate it without using a special parameter `out`.

Comment: @Scheff No reason at all. I just wanted to get the pointer "automatically" without needing to indicate the reference on the function call, which is pretty stupid considering the side effects.

Comment: @BrunoGiannotti Ah, you just tried this. It's not as bad as you might afraid. There is something like [Return Value Optimization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) which makes it more optimal as you would expect on the first glance.